# Not able to decode jwt token in JMeter using PostProcessor

Tags: groovy, jmeter, jwt, load-testing

I am new to JMeter.I want to perfrom some load testing on one of my application.
I want to decode JWT token and from there need to get Session id and it has to be appended to JMeter variable.

Below is my code

```
import com.auth0.jwt.*

log.info("Hello")
def jwt = JWT.decode(vars.get('idToken'))
log.info(jwt)

vars.put('sessionId', jwt.getClaim('sessionId').asString())
log.info(jwt.getClaim('sessionId').asString())
```

It is producing some errors while executing this code

Below is the exception message

```
javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: JWT for class: Script11
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:320) ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyCompiledScript.eval(GroovyCompiledScript.java:71) ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    at javax.script.CompiledScript.eval(CompiledScript.java:93) ~[java.scripting:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223TestElement.processFileOrScript(JSR223TestElement.java:217) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.extractor.JSR223PostProcessor.process(JSR223PostProcessor.java:45) [ApacheJMeter_components.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.runPostProcessors(JMeterThread.java:955) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:573) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:489) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831) [?:?]
```

Need suggestion to resolve this issue.

JMeter Version : 5.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have `java-jwt-x.xx.x.jar` along with its [dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) in [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) before running the script.

For the [latest stable version 3.18.1](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.auth0/java-jwt/3.18.1) you will need the following .jars:

- jackson-annotations-2.11.0.jar
- jackson-core-2.11.0.jar
- jackson-databind-2.11.0.jar
- java-jwt-3.18.1.jar

If you do have them in JMeter Classpath already you will have to **restart JMeter** to pick the libraries up

Once done you should be able to use the code you copied and pasted from somewhere:

Demo using JWT token `eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c` from https://jwt.io/ web page:

[image]

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Added  **java-jwt-3.18.1.jar** in lib folder.Still fill facing same issue

Comment: Resolved it by adding file in  **/usr/local/Cellar/jmeter/5.3/libexec/lib** path